# Iron Router Get Current Item?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Right now I have two routes in my application. There's the main page route that has a list of Ideas (just text items) and then there's a route for showing and editing Ideas.

My problem is with editing ideas... I'm not sure how to actually get the item being edited and persist the changes. I could use a global variable, but that's almost certainly a hack and not the "meteor way" (or the right way in any software, for that matter.) I could use the `Session`, but that doesn't seem quite right to me either... I got the impression that `Session` was just for visual things (like hiding stuff temporarily.)

So here's the relevant code I have so far:

```
Router.route('/idea/:_id', function() {
    var idea = Ideas.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    // Should I save this.params._id in a Session?
    // Is that "the meteor way"?
    this.render('ShowIdea', {data: idea});
}, {
    name: 'idea.show'
});

Template.ShowIdea.events({
    "input div": function (event) {
        var newText = $(event.target).text();
        console.log("newText: " + newText);
        // this event gets called at the right time, and I can see the new text,
        // but how do I know which item to save it on?
    }
});
```

Not much to see for the template, but here it is:

```
<template name="ShowIdea">
    <div contentEditable="true">{{text}}</div>
</template>
```

Also, two side questions:

1 - Is `$(event.target).text()` the best way of extracting the new text? I couldn't think of anything else, but it seems a bit long winded to me.

2 - Is there some comprehensive documentation to Iron-Router somewhere? I see a QuickStart and a Guide, but there doesn't seem to be a straight up list of Objects and Methods anywhere for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your approach is good. 
To save the new text just do something like:

```
Ideas.update(this._id, {$set: {text: newText}});
```

You can use `this._id` because you already set your data context in the router with `data: idea`, so in your `Template.ShowIdea.helpers/events` "this" refers to the specific idea.

Concerning your side questions:

1. You could also use [template.find()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_find) like this :

   ```
   "input div": function (event, template) {
     var newText = template.find("div").text();
   }
   ```

But it is less straightforward and I think that `event.target` is better as the DOM element is already populated (also note the [difference](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) between `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` but there is no issue in your example).

2. I never found any other documentation for Iron Router apart the Guide you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that `this` would be referring to the `idea` instance. I slightly modified your code... I'm pretty sure `{_id: this._id}` is the same as `this._id`. I tried both and didn't see any difference, and this page of Try Meteor just uses `this._id` in their `update()`: https://www.meteor.com/try/5

Comment: I did not remember the syntax for a selector without curly braces for the ID.

Comment: Now I have some funky behavior from the fact that editing my div causes changes in my database causes changes in my div. Is there a built-in way of handling this in Meteor that you know of, or am I going to have to handle this myself (doesn't seem too hard to handle, just, from what I've seen so far, Meteor tends to have a pretty extensive set of batteries included.)

Comment: What change? The 'text' should remain the same. 
Usually when I am creating an UI to update something, upon successful update I redirect the user to another page with Iron Router (Router.redirect or Router.go).

Comment: The database changes, so the template, which watches that database, sees that there's a change and updates the text. It happens to be updating it to what it already is, but Safari is seeing the div as having changed from something besides me, so resetting my cursor back to the start. This is going to be an issue I definitely need to fix, since I want it to be possible for multiple users to concurrently edit the same object in the database. But I think this is beyond the scope of my original question. I'll try figuring it out myself now (unless you have pointers)& open a new question if needed.

Comment: Not sure what the reason is, maybe it is linked to the use of contentEditable rather of <input> ? Good luck :)